# Apache2 SSL Certificate error

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, debian, ssl, ssl-certificate

I bought a Cert. at checkdomain.
They gave me two files a **.crt** and a **.ca-bundle** and **.key**.
I moved them to "/etc/ssl/g/".
I enabled SSL with "a2enmod ssl" and restarted the apache by using "sudo service apache2 restart", no error till then.

Then I edited default-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mrgrimod.de
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/g/g.crt
SSlCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/g/g.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I tried to restart the apache by using "sudo service apache2 restart" but it fails to restart and spills out that error: `Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`

The apache error log contained these lines:

```
 Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143429 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143530 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143557 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143578 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143599 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143620 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143640 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143660 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143674 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143704 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key server1.server1.de:443:0, check /etc/ssl/ssl.key/server.key
```

Comment: An ongoing brute force attack against your SSH is flooding the actually useful lines from your `journalctl -xn` output.

Comment: Go look at the error logs for apache instead. They'll probably be in /var/log/httpd/.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yeah I updated it but still same. That s the output.

Comment: @JennyD Added it but t they don t seem very usefull: https://pastebin.com/G45Vkkg0

Comment: The log at that link seems like an access log. You need to look at the *error* log.

Comment: @JennyD Sry, my fault, here is the new one: https://pastebin.com/AnLPQatQ

Comment: This line pretty much sums up the problem.  `[Fri Mar 30 17:03:50.143704 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 10598:tid 3074262784] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key server1.server1.de:443:0, check /etc/ssl/ssl.key/server.key`

Comment: You should also define the `SSLCertificateFile`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Checkdomain gave me an unvalid Private Key. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command `apachectl -t` to check for any syntax error's before restart the `apache` service.
The command should output `Syntax OK` if no error's are found.

You should include more details regarding your `.conf` files before we could decide what's the error.

Regardless, this is a configuration example for enabling SSL support:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mycert.pem
SSlCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mycert.pem
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
</VirtualHost>
```

To enable SSL, the configuration file must include at minimal the following options:

SSLEngine On: turn support for SSL.

SSLCertificateFile: The location of the singed certificate you were provided.

SSlCertificateKeyFile: The key file that was generated on your system.

Also, a required approach by many browser to justify the request's to your site, is to include the chain file -the one called bundle- using the configuration option `SSLCertificateChainFile`

And I would suggest the following reference's:
Apache how-to : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: SSLCertificateChainFile is deprecated.  SSLCertificateFile should be used.  See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile

Comment: I followed your instructions but now it says: `Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key mrgrimod.de:443:0, check /etc/ssl/g/g.pem`

Comment: @MrGrimod, that mean you have an invalid key file. You need to check your key's man.

Answer (score 0):

To verify your certificate you can use the following command and check the result from the modulus of the Cert and the Key file, it must be the same.

openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/g/g.crt

openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/g/g.key

Also, you can check the file permission on your directory /etc/ssl/g/
just for test you can chmod -R 777 /etc/ssl/g content and restart apache service

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention to anyone who have this error, or other on apache with https
have to add 
Listen 443 on my apache conf